# Creating a generic function in Java with an object containing an id

Tags: java, typescript, generics

In Typescript I can write the following function to check whether an object has an id:

```
function hasId<T extends { id?: number | null }>(something: T): boolean {
  if (!something) {
    return false;
  }

  return something.id != null;
}
```

But is this also possible in Java without using a base class because I have no access to the classes. All the classes implements `Serializable` though.

Comment: No. Java uses a [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) type system, whereas typescript uses a [structural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) one. They are very different.

Comment: It's possible without a base _class_, but not without a base _type_ (e.g., `interface HasId`).

Comment: In addition to doing it with a base type, it can also be done with reflection.